# What is the best way to set up an impressive front page for a Microsoft Excel Workbook that references specific data within the individual worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a very quick CMDB (Configuration Management Database) within Excel. It has different worksheets that refer to laptops, desktops, printers, etc. I want a front sheet that I can brand and also reference information from the different sheets. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have totals of the number of Desktops, Laptops, Printers etc, totals of the different Windows versions...

All easy done with the COUNTIF's formula, then just design your images/layout around that for the front page? :)

Comment: Thanks Haydn. What is the best way to design the layout?

Comment: Personally i'd just create it as a sheet in Excel as it'd be easier - the draw tools within 2010 are quite good (but i'm no graphic designer). The danger of having a completely seperate front page/written in a seperate program, is it not being 'active/live' (failing to update itself should anything change).

Comment: How did you get along? Happy with my answer or need more help/info?